# Find and Print first three biggest integer values from arraylist

Tags: arraylist, integer, max

```
List<Integer> zmagovalci = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if (zmagovalci != null && !zmagovalci.isEmpty()) { 

if (zmagovalci.size() == 1)

{System.out.println("Zmagal je Tekmovalec " + zmagovalci.get(0) + "   " + "("+
stTockZmagovalca + " tock" + ")");
```

This code returns/prints me the biggest value from the arraylist. How can i print the first three biggest (descending) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking purely Java then you can achieve it like so

```
Collections.sort(zmagovalci);
Collections.reverse(zmagovalci);
```

To print the largest 3 numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
System.out.println(zmagovalci.get(i));
}
```

**Edit**

Here is how I'd solve this now using Java 8:

```
 zmagovalci.stream()
            .sorted(reverseOrder())
            .limit(3)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Java 8 is sooooo much nicer :)

Comment: this sorts it in a descending order right?
but how do you "System.out.print" those 3 from the arraylist?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the printing out of the largest 3

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select the largest 3 elements. Let n be the number of elements in the list and k be the number of elements you want to select. You can:

1. Loop through the list and keep track of the 3 largest elements. The simple approach using just 3 variables doesn't scale well but you can use a heap to generalize the problem with good performance. This runs in O(n log k).
2. Sort the list in descending order and then print the first 3 elements. This runs in O(n log n + k) in general.
3. Implement a selection algorithm such as [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to select the largest 3. This is more involved but you can also choose to print just the 3rd largest element, or from 5th to 7th, etc efficiently. It runs in O(nk).

Answer (score 0):

Sort the ArrayList and then get the first 3 elements.